# Transpose dataset and append different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like this:

```
date | a | diff_a | b | diff_b | c | diff_c
2020   0     NaN    10    Nan    5    NaN
2021   1     1      20    10     7     2
2022   3     2      30    10     13    6
2023   4     1      40    10     20    7
```

And I want to transpose this dataset and merge different columns below, like this:

```
date | Cat |  value  | diff 
2020   a      0      NaN
2021   a      1      1
2022   a      3      2
2023   a      4      1
2020   b      10     ...
2021   b      20
2022   b      30
2023   b      40
2020   c      5
2021   c      7
2022   c      13
2023   c      20
```

The diff is not important since if I can put the other columns below I can just filter and then concat the dataframes, but how do I pass this columns to rows?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach with [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt)

```
m=df.columns.str.contains('diff')

new_df = (df.melt(df.columns[~m],df.columns[m],var_name='Cat',value_name = 'diff')
            .assign(Cat = lambda x: x['Cat'].str.split('_').str[-1],
                    a = lambda x: x.lookup(x.index, x.Cat)))
new_df = new_df.drop(columns = list(filter(lambda x: x != 'a',new_df.Cat.unique())))

print(new_df)
    date   a Cat diff
0   2020   0   a  NaN
1   2021   1   a    1
2   2022   3   a    2
3   2023   4   a    1
4   2020  10   b  Nan
5   2021  20   b   10
6   2022  30   b   10
7   2023  40   b   10
8   2020   5   c  NaN
9   2021   7   c    2
10  2022  13   c    6
11  2023  20   c    7
```

**EDIT**

If we do not want the diff column we can delete it, also if the column does not have to call `a` we can do:

```
m=df.columns.str.contains('diff')

new_df = (df.melt(df.columns[~m],df.columns[m],var_name='Cat',value_name = 'diff')
            #.drop(columns = 'diff') #if you want drop diff
            .assign(Cat = lambda x: x['Cat'].str.split('_').str[-1],
                    other = lambda x: x.lookup(x.index, x.Cat)))
new_df = new_df.drop(columns = new_df['Cat'])

print(new_df)
    date Cat diff  other
0   2020   a  NaN      0
1   2021   a    1      1
2   2022   a    2      3
3   2023   a    1      4
4   2020   b  Nan     10
5   2021   b   10     20
6   2022   b   10     30
7   2023   b   10     40
8   2020   c  NaN      5
9   2021   c    2      7
10  2022   c    6     13
11  2023   c    7     20
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That is not quite what I want, I want to preserve a and b, which are my categories. Forget about diff, I can calculate that afterwards. I want one column with all the categories, in this case `a` and `b` and then the value on another column.

Comment: is it important that the column is called `a`?

Comment: No, I will change the name, it was just for the example. Thank you very much!
Just one thing, If it is not asking too much, can you do the same without the diff, I am having some trouble understanding it, maybe it will look simpler. Thanks once again!

Comment: what do you mean without diff? 
if you mean that the columns are called differently then you should write a list of columns or use other criteria. 
if you want to delete the diff column I have updated the code for it, you just have to uncomment the line

Comment: Oh, that's perfectly fine, thanks. I am just having an hard time to understand this: `.assign(Cat = lambda x: x['Cat'].str.split('_').str[-1]`
Anyway, upvoted and marked as solved, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I like @ansev answer. Definitely elegant and oozing experience.
My attempt below. Please note I drop the diff columns now that you don't need them and then;

```
df2=df.set_index('date').stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=False).rename_axis('Cat', axis=0).reset_index().sort_values(by='date') 

df2.rename(columns = {0:'value'}, inplace = True)
```